# Text-alignment of generated content in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm debugging [this site](http://www.cityofsleep.com) and trying to sort out some issues that arise in Internet Explorer (big surprise).

I'm adding a sub-title to several links as follows:

```
.subtitle a:after {
    content:"The Subtitle Here";
}
```

On all modern browsers (and IE9) the content is center aligned because the container uses `text-align:center;`. However, in IE8 "The Subtitle Here" is flushed left.

Is there any way to control that with CSS?

Thanks.

Comment: Placing such text into `css:after` isn't a good idea after all.

Comment: In general this is true, but it is not a problem IF the text is truly a design element. Decorative text belongs with CSS in the style layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out you can do it easily:

I added another style rule that targets the added content...

```
.subtitle a:after {
    text-align:center;
}
```

I guess IE9 and other browsers inherit the `text-align` property for `:after` content but IE8 doesn't. IE always keeps it interesting...

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align:center
```

didn't work for me. This is how i got it fixed in IE8. (I have a seperate style sheet for IE8)

```
.printIcon:after {
    content: "Print" !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin-top: 25px !important;
    position:relative !important;
    left:25px !important;
}
```

[image]

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the answers above worked for me because of an underlying issue I had. Apparently IE8 does not support `::after`, I changed it to `:after` and it worked just as intended.

Worth checking for!