# can't get css 'content' property to work in ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

So, I've tried everything I can think of, or have found regarding how to make sure that IE 8 will work with the 'content' property in my page.

No matter what I try though, when viewing in IE9 using F12 dev tools to view in IE8 standards mode, the page simply won't load AT ALL. I get a "page error" when viewing in Adobe's browser tester as well.

As soon as I remove my "content" property line from my css, then it works fine, but of course, then I lose my cool drop-shadows that I'm wanting to use in all the other browsers.

here's the page: http://saks-jewelers.com (the featured product section towards the bottom).

Any thoughts on what I'm missing? (this site is run using magento CE 1.7)

Comment: Your CSS file looks quite large, there's a chance you might be hitting the selector limit:  http://habdas.org/msie-4095-selector-limit/

Comment: possible duplicate of [using :after and content: in Internet Explorer 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996212/using-after-and-content-in-internet-explorer-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both people on IE8 are going to be disappointed! Did you try checking the inspect element in ie8 to see if the error is more specific?

Is your drop-shadow defined in the last CSS loaded?

Comment: I wonder if I hit the limit as mentioned above. I just went through and was cleaning up the css in some other areas (ended up killing several lines) and now IE8 is working, though the floats are all off in IE8 and IE7 vs IE9, but at least the page is not throwing errors.  go figure.

Comment: Ah, Lots of CSS is never good. When you start having to use "important" regularly you know you've gone too far.

Answer (score 1):

The content property will not work in IE8 unless you specify a doctype. This is according to W3C.

Put this at the top of your code and let us know if it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: This did not work, I am trying to get the content property to work for a checkbox.